# PrintWriter class in a separate method

Tags: java, printwriter, println

Hello working on a small program that writes data to a file.  I am using a if else statement for validation so I need the PrintWriter and FileWriter class/declaration in a separate method.  I then call this method with the constructor of the main class.  The problem I am having is when I moved the Printwriter class to it's own method I can no longer access it from my button click aciton l istener.

CODE:

```
private void OpenFilePW(){
    try{
        String inputFileName = "addressBook.txt";
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(inputFileName, true);
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fw);

    }catch(IOException error){
         JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, error);   
    }
}
```

When using outputFile.  I get an error because it can't find outputFile.  Why wont' this work?

Comment: Probably a scope issue? `outputFile` is only defined in the `try` block, so using it elsewhere is obviously a problem. Maybe make it an instance variable?

Comment: Thanks this worked. I didn't realize when you define a variable in the try block it was only visible within that statement. I assumed it was class wide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the PrintWriter as an instance variable in your main calss
not sure what are you trying to use this for

but make it public to get it working or don't use any modifier if you are working in the same class

so your code should be

```
public class MyClass
{
    public PrintWriter outputFile;
.....
}
```

and then instantiate the instance when you get to the method

```
outputFile = new PrintWriter(fw);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.  I didn't realize when you define a variable in the try block it was only visible within that statement.  I assumed it was class wide.

Comment: In fact this is a double problem here, it wasn't working for you not because it's in a try block, all variables declared in a method are local to this and only this method, try to declare an int inside the method but outside the try catch block it would be the same problem.

it's a double problem because even in the same method, a variable in a try block is local to the try block only!

if you want to use it out side you have to declare it outside

Answer (score 0):

First (by convention), Java method names start with a lower case letter. Second, you aren't returning the `PrintWriter` you're assigning it to a method local variable -

```
private PrintWriter openFilePW(){
  try{
    String inputFileName = "addressBook.txt";
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(inputFileName, true);
    return new PrintWriter(fw);
  } catch(IOException error) {
     JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, error);   
  }
  return null;
}
```

Alternatively, you could assign the `PrintWriter` to a class level variable,

```
private PrintWriter outputFile = null;
private void openFilePW(){
  try{
    String inputFileName = "addressBook.txt";
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(inputFileName, true);
    outputFile = new PrintWriter(fw);
  } catch(IOException error) {
     JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, error);   
  }
}
```